# Apache Thrift make err with libthrift-0.10.0.dylib

Tags: macos, thrift, dylib

I am using macOS 10.12.3. 
Yesterday I successfully installed thrift but it could not work correctly with python. So I re-make it today and get this err. Could someone tell me what's wrong. Thx

```
Making all in perl
../../compiler/cpp/thrift --gen perl ../../test/ThriftTest.thrift
dyld: Symbol not found: _GENERAL_NAME_free
  Referenced from: /Users/sara/thrift-0.10.0/lib/cpp/.libs/libthrift-0.10.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/sara/thrift-0.10.0/lib/cpp/.libs/libthrift-0.10.0.dylib
make[3]: *** [gen-perl/ThriftTest/Constants.pm] Abort trap: 6
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, but now I solve it. when you had the error, I think `/usr/local/bin/thrift` is already existed in you macOS. Then run

    `$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/include/thrift/
    $ brew link --overwrite thrift`

then you will find the command `/usr/local/bin/thrift` is ok.